# Hive: select the most recent item from the set

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm looking for a way of choosing the most recent item (date) from the set in Hive. For instance a have the following table `t1`:

```
item       date
a          2016-01-01
a          2016-02-04
b          2016-01-10
```

after

```
hive> select item, collect_set(date) as dates from t1 group by item;
```

i have

```
item       dates
a          [2016-01-01, 2016-02-04]
b          [2016-01-10]
```

So now I need to get rid of absolete dates, i.e., create table like

```
item       date
a          2016-02-04
b          2016-01-10
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `max()`:

```
select item, max(date) as date
from t1
group by item;
```

If you actually want a new table, you can use `create table as`.